# Installation Error :(

Tags: system-installation, kernel

I tried Ubuntu 14.10 (64 & 32 Bit) & Ubuntu 12.10 (64 & 32 Bit) I get this error every time I select & entered "Install Ubuntu" *I am installing Ubuntu using a USB*

```
[21.317787] Kernel panic - Not Syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (2,0)    
[21.317916] Pid: 1, comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.5.0 - 17 - generic #28 Ubuntu    
[21.318033] Call Trace:    
[21.318150] [15bf0ec] panic + 0x81/0x17b    
[21.318269] [c18aede1] mount_block_root + 0x19a/0x23d    
[21.318387] [c115cb1d] ? sys_mlenod + 0x2d/0x30    
[21.318503] [18aeff1] mount_root + 0x5e/0x64    
[21.318615] [c18af145] prepare_namespace + 0x14e/0x192    
[21.318731] [c114da05] ? sys_acces + 0x25/0x30    
[21.318843] [c18ab75] kernel_init + 0x1b1/0x1b6    
[21.318956] [c18ae41c] ? . loglevel + 0x25/0x25    
[21.319068] [c18ae9c4] ? start_kernet + 0x363/0.363    
[21.319184] [c15d04fe] kernel_thread_helper + 0x6/0x10
```

Comment: Looks like you've got a bad block on your ISO file download or on your USB stick itself.  Did you check the md5sum?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the image in the USB stick is damaged. You may try wirting the image again. If it fails again, then try another USB stick, or a DVD with Ubuntu.
During the installation, select "Install allongside with Ubuntu 12.10" and partition your HDD. Or you may also select the "Something else" option to make partitions as you want.